# How to draw a circular 3D plot in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to plot this function in matlab : `sin(4*x)*cos(4*y)` on a disk

This is how i proceeded :

```
syms x y;
f=@(x,y) sin(4*x)*cos(4*y);
ezmesh(f,'circ')
```

This method works with `f=@(x,y) sin(2*x)*cos(2*y);`

but with a more quickly varying function like `f=@(x,y) sin(4*x)*cos(4*y);` ezmesh mistakes these variations for discontinuities.
the problem is i can't use the 'circ' parameter and increase the number of points that ezmesh uses at the same time (ezmesh didn't accept it)

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it can be done by adding another parameter. However, if you want a quick-and-dirty way, here you go:

```
x = -2*pi:0.1:2*pi;
y = -2*pi:0.1:2*pi;
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
zz = sin(4*xx).*cos(4*yy);
zz(xx.^2 +yy.^2 >(2*pi)^2) = 0;
surf(xx,yy,zz);
```

Which produces:

[image: sin(4x)*cos(4x) on Disk]